# Объявление класса-наследника, который вызывает конструктор базового класса в header-файле

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую. Как правильно вызывать конструктор базового класса в header файле?

Сейчас делаю так:

ArduinoManager.h:

```
class ArduinoManager : public SoftwareSerial
{
    public:
        ArduinoManager() : SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(SOFTSERIAL_RX, SOFTSERIAL_TX){

        }

        void send_command(String text);
};
```

И ArduinoManager.cpp

```
#include "ArduinoManager.hpp"

void ArduinoManager::send_command(String text) 
{
    
}
```

Правильно ли это, что реализация конструктора класса ArduinoManager объявляется в .h файле?

Comment: Делать это в хедере изначально неправильно.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, как можно сделать по-другому?

Comment: можно в хедере, можно в cpp. Все зависит от конкретных целей.

Comment: Правильно:     `ArduinoManager() : SoftwareSerial(SOFTSERIAL_RX, SOFTSERIAL_TX) { }` cpp в данном представлении не нужно, потому что в заголовочном файле конструктор уже определен

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cpp+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81+c%2B%2B+%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80&oq=cpp+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81+c%2B%2B+%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.695j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: KoVadim, а если, допустим, мне нужно просто объявить сам конструктор в .h файле, а в cpp - его реализацию? Как это можно сделать?

Comment: в хедере будет `ArduinoManager();`, в cpp будет `ArduinoManager::ArduinoManager() : SoftwareSerial(SOFTSERIAL_RX, SOFTSERIAL_TX){}` и никаких проблем

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо большое! Просто, когда  я пытался туда запихнуть ещё и SoftwareSerial - возникало куча проблем. Не знал о таком способе.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков гугл выдает совершенно разные ссылки в зависимости от того, что Вы искали до этого. Поэтому, просто так бросаться ссылкой на гугл как минимум грубо. Если у Вас есть ссылки на доверенные источники - приводите их.

Comment: Я не понимаю людей, которые  "не умеют  гвоздь забивать, а берутся строить дом".. Какое вам дело до ардуиновской библиотеки, если вы класс не можете писать и не знаете примитивы языка?

Comment: а иначе никак не научится. Если бы не пытался делать свой проект, то возможно никогда и не узнал бы о такой возможности.

Comment: @KoVadim это не так. На этот запрос будут выведены +- те же ссылки что и у меня. И я не стремился показать какой-то конкретный сайт, а лишь дал ссылку на хороший запрос к гуглу.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я всегда так делал. Криво но делал. Обои в комнате помню клеил, криво, но получилось же...

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков нет, такой гарантии нет. Вот абсолютно нет. Гугл складывает свой вывод по ему ведомым алгоритмам. Но также стоит помнить, что чтобы увидеть правильный ответ, нужно знать как он выглядит. Если этого не знать, очень сложно увидеть правильный ответ...

Comment: @KoVadim гарантии что гугл не отрубится навсегда через минуту тоже нет.

Comment: и такое бывает, но это уже отошли от темы.

Comment: @Никита Самоуков, потому у нас все всегда получается "криво и как всегда...", а у других получается как надо, потому что они сначала учатся, а потом  применяют свои знания.   Лучше, чтобы никто не брал с вас пример....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишем где то так

ArduinoManager.h:

```
class ArduinoManager : public SoftwareSerial
{
    public:
        ArduinoManager();
        void send_command(String text);
};
```

И ArduinoManager.cpp

#include "ArduinoManager.hpp"

```
ArduinoManager::ArduinoManager() : SoftwareSerial(SOFTSERIAL_RX, SOFTSERIAL_TX)
{

}

void ArduinoManager::send_command(String text) 
{
    
}
```